# django foreignkey not working

Tags: python, django

I am still not satisfied with django foreignkey relationship.
below are two classess .

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class PhotoGallery(models.Model):  
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    picture_choices = 
    models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=PICTURE_CHOICES,default=NTR)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='image_uploader')
    date_posted =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True,unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


from django.contrib import admin
from gallery.models import PhotoGallery

class PhotoGalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
```

And below is `class Imagesmodel` that has a foreignkey .Calling the `PhotoGallery` class from `class Imagesmodel` is not a problem .MY big problem is doing the reverse

```
 class ImagesModel(models.Model):
      gala_obj =
         models.ForeignKey(PhotoGallery,
         related_name='picture_gallery',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
         post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery_pics',
                          verbose_name='Image')


   def __str__(self):
         return self.gala_obj.title
```

and below is my `views.py` file

```
    `def detailViewPage(request,slug):
          #here i wanted to get one image with the given slug 
          from `ImagesModel`
          a = get_object_or_404(PhotoGallery, slug=slug)
          selected_pic = a.picture_gallery.all()



         #here  i wanted to get all images excluding one 
         with the given slug
         object_2 = ImagesModel.objects.exclude(id=selected_pic.id)
         .order_by('-id')[:15]



         return render(request,'gallery/photogallery_detail.html',{
                                    'selected_pic':selected_pic,
                                    'object_2':object_2,
                                })`
```

below is the error i  get
[image]

Comment: I wanted to return a matching object for the given slug

Comment: This question is not clear. The slug is on model A, and your code will work perfectly to get an instance of model A with the matching slug. B does not have a slug field. What does B have to do with anything here? What is the *exact* result you want?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `ForeignKey`s work, the `title` in the `B` class is not a title at all, it is a `A` object, and in the database it has the same type as the primary key.

Comment: why cant you directly search `A` for that `slug`  ? or do you want the related `B` of that `slug`?

Comment: Furthermore it is strange to search for a *single* `B` that has as a related `A` a specific slug: there can be *multiple* such `B`s. How will you decide which one it is?

Comment: I have images from class B that are related to class B by the foreignkey. i wanted to get an image with other information from class A like user and title.  when i try to run the function in `views.py`  `picture = get_object_or_404(A, slug=slug)` I get an error that the  `class A ` model has no attribute slug

Comment: That error is *not possible* with the code you have given. I think in the process of anonymizing your code you have become confused about what A and B are, and what fields each has. Please post your actual code and the full error.

Comment: You probably mean "I have images from class **`A`**"? But nevertheless, what will you do if `A` has no images, or two or more?

Comment: the problem is clear from the error message, queryset doesn't have id, it is a queryset. You have to loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but I assume you want to get all pictures associated with an object A. In your B model, give your foreignkey a related name:

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A,related_name='post_title', related_name='pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery_pics',
                          verbose_name='Image')
```

In your views.py:

```
a = get_object_or_404(A, slug=slug)
b = a.pictures.all()
```

I don't know why you named your foreignkey 'title', but the above code will get all the pictures associated with the object A.

The following will work also:

```
a = get_object_or_404(A, slug=slug)
pictures = a.b_set.all()
```

If you want to get the slug from an object B, then you can do the following:

```
b = get_object_or_404(B, id=1)
slug = b.a.slug
```

Comment: i have updated my code , and my big problem i think is reverse reference when working with django foreignkey

Comment: @SeyyidSaid Your update doesn't make the question any more clearer. Is your objective to select an image from a gallery and then exclude it from that gallery? or is it to select an image from a gallery, and exclude it from a list of all images? Either way, you need to identify the image first through its own id, not through the gallery's slug.

Comment: i wanted to have two objects . each object is to have a `title`, `description` and also an associated image from `ImagesModel` .Also the first object is specific to the given `slug -> selected_pic` . in the other object am fetching all the objects from database execept  the one with the stated slug

Comment: @SeyyidSaid in your code, selected_pic returns a queryset, not an object (that's why you are getting the error). This is because you are getting all images associated with the gallery. If you want to get one image from the gallery, for example the first image, then do the following `selected_pic = a.picture_gallery.all()[0]`. This will solve the error, but still doesn't make sense to me. You should set a slug for image model, and that way you know which image from which gallery you want to work with.

Comment: thank you very much it worked. Also if i could get a reference guide on django ORM , it will be much helpfull. Thanks @almost a beginner